# Is "needs details or clarity" too subjective to be a useful closing criterion?

Tags: discussion, questions, close-reasons

I have noticed that some questions that are closed with the "needs details or clarity" tag are in fact perfectly clear and specific questions, often with simple and straightforward answers. This is not an infrequent occurrence - I believe I see examples every day. Here are three examples from the last 24 hours:

- [Theoretically, is it feasible for the dark matter density to be constant and homogeneous, as dark energy is, and the two to be related?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/784174)
- [Bell's inequality for angles 120°](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/784162)
- [Interference with multiple beams](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/784137)

I don't think I am alone in thinking that these questions are in fact completely clear and specific, since (a) in some cases other posters have put answers in comments which correspond with my understanding of the question and (b) these questions are quite often re-opened on review, sometimes without any significant changes.

Obviously if I believe the question should not have been closed then I can (and do) vote to re-open. But I am puzzled by the frequency with which this criterion is being incorrectly applied. Is there some explanation for this ? Is this tag being used as "shorthand" for some other reason for closing these questions ? Or could this test be too subjective to be useful as a closing criterion?

Comment: In the second question (into which I bumped accidentally), the quantity P is not even *defined*! There is no way to know what the question is asking, without making some guesses.

Comment: ... just to add to this, after some comtemplation I came up with an entirely different interpretation of what the answer to the OPs question is, for which I equally have no idea whether it is correct or not. For me, the question *definitely* needs details or clarity.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch $P(a,b)$ is the correlation between the measurements of two particles with opposite spins made by two detectors with settings $a$ and $b$. This is the notation used in Bell's original paper https://cds.cern.ch/record/111654/files/vol1p195-200_001.pdf, in this Wikipedia article https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem and in many textbooks. Anyone familiar with Bell's theorem would know this.

Comment: @gandalf61 At the risk of sounding snippy (I'm not trying to be snippy, I'm just rushed), anyone familiar with Bell's theorem would also be able to edit your single clarifying sentence into the question. Or as a clarifying comment: "by $P$, do you mean ...? if so, please `[edit]`."

Comment: @gandalf61 Let me point out that the OP accepted a different answer, which had a very different interpretation from what the question was looking for than what your guess was. So yes, the question was (and is) lacking clarity.

Answer (score 9):

There is a difference between "I can tell what this question is asking" and "The question is perfectly specific and clear". Remember: Questions should be useful for *other* users on the site, too, not only for the person who asked them, so the level of clarify and details in a question should be such that most readers who encounter the question will be clearly able to tell what it is about.

Of your three examples, I do not agree that *any* of them was "specific and clear" when it was closed (and I didn't vote on any of these questions):

1. The question is only in the title and not in the body. In fact, I opened this question and was completely mystified why anyone would think this question is clear because *there isn't a question in the body at all*. Even if we ignore this poor formatting decision, the body is still mostly unclear - what does a statement like *"But if both are included in a generalized gravitation theory, the picture can change."* even mean? What is a "generalized gravitation theory" in this context? Are you *certain* what this user wants to know is really the observational facts?
2. The question was much improved by an edit after being closed and so is a perfect example of an unclear question becoming clearer after being closed, i.e. it does not support the point in the question at all.
3. This is somewhat of a pet peeve of mine: Yes, people with the same book or who have been taught using the same notation can tell what this question is asking, but the question itself gives *no context at all* for what any of the symbols here mean. What are 'd', 'theta', 'k'? To a reader unfamiliar with this specific choice of notation the question is *completely* mystifying (and no, I do not believe that "but this notation is very standard" is a good counterargument here).

   Alas, in this case I *do* believe that you (and probably I, too) perfectly well understand what the question is about. But instead of complaining that other users who don't (or who think the asker should make the effort to phrase the question in a way accessible to everyone) close the question, I think the correct action is just this: If you really like this question and think it should be open, then *edit* it so it is really specific and clear to *everyone* without having to make a bunch of educated guesses.

So altogether I don't think the problem here is that a question being "unclear" is very subjective as such, it's that you seem to apply a much weaker interpretation of "clarity" (i.e.: you think that you personally have a reasonable guess of what the question means) than the close voters (i.e.: every reader familiar with the topic the question is about should have an unambiguous idea of what the question means).

Comment: "The question is only in the title and not in the body." - I think that's a ridiculous reason to close a question, but now that I am aware that some closers may be applying it then it is easily remedied.

Comment: "Every reader should have an unambiguous idea of what the question means" - really ?? *Every* reader - even those who know nothing about the topic that's being asked about ? Does every question have to fully explain every technical term and every piece of notation that it uses ?? That's an absurdly high bar, and 90% of our questions will fail it.

Comment: @gandalf61 1. Note that the thing about the question in the title is only *part* of my criticism of that question and I'm not claiming specifically that the question was closed because of this formatting decision alone. 2. I didn't mean that; of course I don't expect questions to be understandable by people who know nothing at all about the topic. What I mean is that people who are capable of understanding the question shouldn't need to make any *guesses*.